# Change language of Google websites?

Tags: google, localization

Google have set my language to dutch but I hate it for a million reasons and one of these is when something is wrong I could get a lot more help if I get feedback from Google in English. Is there a way to set my language to english and preferably keep it there.

I am talking about sites like google+, Developer Console, Play store (Somehow this is in english), Drive, etc.

Comment: The language options only stay set if you log in with a google account; if you open a google page without logging in, you get the default.  If the play store is in English, it's probably because you set your browser to log you in automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the language for all of Google's products by setting your preferred language at this URL:

> https://myaccount.google.com/u/0/language
>
> To change the display language for Google Accounts, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Sign in to [My Account](https://myaccount.google.com/).
> 2. In the "Account preferences" section, select **Language & Input Tools**.
> 3. Choose **Language**
> 4. To change your language, select edit Edit .
> 5. Choose your language from the dropdown box and select **Ok**.
>    **<sub>Source: [Google FAQ](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32047?source=gsearch&hl=en)</sub>**

Comment: Yes that worked I tried "http://www.google.com/preferences?hl=en-US#languages" before without success.

Comment: You're welcome :) If you are not logged into your Google account and would like to use Google search in English (by default, Google redirects you to the country specific site) use [http://google.com/ncr](http://google.com/ncr) (NCR stands for No Country Redirect. It'll redirect you to a 'generic' Google search website)